# Boot/Grub issue after installing a Windows VM

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

although I have been working for some time with Ubuntu I am now facing a problem that is above my experience/capabilities to solve.

Some days ago I installed a VM with Windows, everything worked well for some days. Now, I don't know if it is related, I pressed Crtl + Alt + F12 accidentally and since then I can't boot anymore. I am automatically directed to the GRUB terminal (grub> not grub rescue>).

The first thing I checked is just checking the partitions and typing ls just gives back

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd1) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) error: Failure reading sector 0x100800 from 'hd1'.
```

Then I started with the what seems to be to usual first thing. I booted from an Ubuntu (20.04, same as installed OS) live USB and installed boot-repair. However, Boot-Repair does not show me the *Recommended Repair* option.

This is the link to the Boot-Info summary, created by Boot-Repair.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tzt576SVdX/

If I follow the instructions to reinstall grub via the terminal, sudo fdisk -l returns

```
Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0   6599743   6599744  3.2G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       5930192   5938191      8000  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb3       6602752 120176639 113573888 54.2G 83 Linux
```

and sudo blkid

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="72AA-EE87" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition"  

PARTUUID="4bc4e648-1726-4230-8bf7-6f4862ec62ae"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="2022-02-23-09-09-33-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="1693364d" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="1693364d-01"
/dev/sdb2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="54C5-9C6C" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="1693364d-02"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="writable" UUID="7cb33c86-ce17-4b2a-a8f8-e3b509f91879" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1693364d-03"
```

From this I see that my Ubuntu is on sdb3. So I mount it in
sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt
and run
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdb
and get the error message

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: Attempting to install GRUB to a disk with multiple partition labels.  This is not supported yet..
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

As commented when I try to use gparted to resize the sdb2 partion I get

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gparted
Unit boot.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
GParted 1.0.0
configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize
libparted 3.3
Input/output error during read on /dev/nvme0n1
```

Now the most alarming part, as I had planned to sometimes soon reset my OS anyway I thought I can quickly access the data which I haven|t backed up via the live USB, save it and I am okay. So I mount in the partition and now ls returns only a root and lost+found directory, and nothing else.

I would be very grateful for any kind of help/advice on what else I can do. If you need more information, I would ask you to let me know so that I can provide it.

Thank you all.

Wishes,
David

Answer (score 0):

i think the size of your sdb2 EFI partition is too small (3.9M) for grub to be installed there... try resizing it with gparted to something like 100~200MB at least and then retry grub installation.

Edit: Try to install and use this with live usb... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, gparted is not possible to read the partition.

Comment: I added the output of launching gparted to the question.